# How can I refresh the plus count on a Google+ badge

Tags: google-plus

I'm looking for a way to refresh the plus count on a Google+ badge using javascript, without refreshing the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to remove the +1 button from the page and insert a new one using the [explicit render](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#example-explicit-render) feature.

Comment: This isn't the ideal solution, as the user experience is pretty bad.. but it's probably the closest we can get to an answer on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should disable automatic rendering by setting parsetags to explicit after plusone.js is loaded. You can set it as follows;

```
window.___gcfg = {
  parsetags: 'explicit'
};
```

And whenever you want to refresh the badge, use one of the following button-rendering functions:

```
gapi.plusone.go('#container-of-google-badge');
gapi.plusone.render('#google-badge');
```

More information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/#jsapi).